# NFC: GET_VERSION FROM NTAG isn't working

Tags: c#, winapi, nfc

I'm playing with ACR122U PICC reader/writer with different tags of the line NXP 210/212/214/215/216.
Under Windows 7 using winscard.dll (Windows component).
From C#.
I can Initialize the reader, I can connect to the TAG, but when send 60h command (Get_Version) it returns no error but also no data.
Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public  static extern int SCardTransmit (int hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, ref byte RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

Reader connection's done with no errors, and I can see that in returned parameters and visually (LED and "USB_pluggedIn" sound).

```
retCode = ModWinsCard.SCardConnect(hContext, cbReader.SelectedItem.ToString(), ModWinsCard.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref Protocol);
```

and the call from the application:

```
private void Test_NXP_NTAG203()
{
    pioSendRequest.dwProtocol = Protocol;
    pioSendRequest.cbPciLength = 8;

    pioRecvRequest.dwProtocol = Protocol;
    pioRecvRequest.cbPciLength = 8;

    SendBuff[0] = 0x60;
    SendLen = 5; //  SendBuff.Length;
    string err = ModWinsCard.GetScardErrMsg(
        ModWinsCard.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref pioSendRequest, ref SendBuff[0], SendLen, ref pioRecvRequest, ref RecvBuff[0], ref RecvLen));
}
```

The size of the buffers = 256 each. 
Protocol value is the one returned after Connection = 2;

Please, any hint or idea to advance me further into that technology...
Spent several days trying this&that without success.. no reply..

I have the DOC in PDF, if someone needs I'll send it..

Comment: Which version of the ACR122U do you use? What commands do you use to detect/read/write the tag?

Comment: It's ACR122U-A9... Get_VERSION->60h

Comment: Again, what commands do you currently use to detect/read/write the tag?

Comment: proximity commands, and just getData... it's NXP216 chip, so... I don't have another SDK, only the one which comes with the reader.

Comment: The point behind my question is that I'm not sure what the version "-A9" is and for the ACR122U it heavily depends on the device version that you have how you would issue the GET_VERSION command. Hence, you need to clearly describe how you currently use that reader.

Comment: I've described everything, pls, see my question..

Comment: So you are essentially saying that you haven't tried anything else than the above so far? This means that you, up to now, connected to the *reader* (not necessarily the *tag*) and are unable to send any command. Have you read the manual of the reader?

Comment: I can read ATR... the Q about GET_VERSION, mate, have you read my Q? :)

Comment: I have already contacted to ACS support team, thanks for your help.

Comment: I did indeed read your question. So far you seem to use SCardConnect. With most versions of the ACR122U this connects you to the reader (and **not** the tag). Only some versions of the ACR122U perform automatic anti-collision and enumeration of tags. For those versions SCardConnect may implicitly connect you to the tag as well. You seem to be able to obtain an ATR (that's **not** mentioned in your question btw).

Comment: Since NTAG21x (or in fact no NFC tag) has an ATR, it's again the card reader (ACR122U) that *emulates* an ATR. Depending on the version of the reader this is either a static value that is just a placeholder to allow SCardConnect to succeed (i.e. the reader simulates a card so that SCardConnect/SCardTransmit can be used to exchange commands with the reader) or, if the reader perfroms automatic anti-collision, this may be an emulated ATR providing information about the enumerated tag according to the PC/SC specification.

Comment: Thus, your question does, by far, not provide sufficient information to be answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106392/discussion-between-vitali-petrov-and-michael-roland).

Comment: Were you able to resolve the correct command?